# How get last added text from column into different sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I get the last added plain text from a column in sheet1, which also has empty rows, into a cell of a sheet2?

With help I managed to do this with the last added date, but with plain text I am stuck.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Still very interested in answer.....
Am trying to help a friend getting his business a bit more organized. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

This formula works perfect:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A<>""),
         COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A<>""))))
```

(found the answer somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
=index(Sheet1!A:A,match("z¬",Sheet1!A:A))
```

BUT relies on ColumnA of Sheet1 being all Text.